# How to remove all default gateways

Tags: linux, ip, routing

I'm running a custom built Linux machine, so **not all Linux commands are available**.
I execute network related commands, so I need to **set a default gateway** right before I run my command, then remove that gateway immediately afterward.

To do that I run all my commands in one line:

```
/sbin/route add default gw 10.10.10.10;my command;/sbin/route del default gw 10.10.10.10;
```

The problem is, for some reason I once found 2 default gateways on the same machine which caused all my commands to fail because even if I set my default gateway before running my test, it is still messed up and can't run my test.

So is there a way to **remove ALL default gateways in one command** ? I have a large amount of machines that are increasing and it won't be practical to plant a script on every machine. I need a command as **simple** as the following:

```
/sbin/route del all default;set my default gw;mycommand;/sbin/route del all default;
```

All I have found so far is a command to remove **a** default gateway but not all of them
`/sbin/route del default` which won't work for me.

`/sbin/route` help displays the following

```
/sbin/route --help

Usage: route [{add|del|delete}]

Edit the kernel's routing tables

Options:
        -n      Don't resolve names
        -e      Display other/more information
        -A inet Select address family
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the answers are great but I resolved this problem using a different approach, I used the command to add only one default gateway, but fail if there is already one. And thus eventually remove the wrong gateway at the end of the command. This should work the second time inshallah.

```
ip route add default via my-gateway
ip route del default
```

Answer (score 22):

If you use `ip` instead of `route`, you could simply run:

```
ip route del 0/0
```

I believe that catches all default routes.

Comment: Thank you but it still removes only one default gateway, not all.

Comment: Then perhaps you should iterate through all default routes, and remove them, instead of assuming that your first remove removes all of them.

It sounds like your code is breaking somehow and adding more than one default route.  This is not a normal circumstance.

Comment: I agree that my code breaks at some point but may be I can solve this quickly by fixing the GW thing instead of wasting a lot of time which I don't have. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This is modern linux only.

Answer (score 7):

To remove all default gateways using `ip`

```
ip route flush 0/0
```

Comment: Note that for clarity you can also write this as `ip route flush default`.

Answer (score 2):

If your code breaks with multiple default gateways you should probably also look in multiple ip addresses per device.

As you received already an answer here is another approach as you should **NEVER** change the configuration of your system just because you want to run/test a script. How about using network namespaces instead. For a short introduction how to add virtual devices to your NS (namespace) have a look at http://code.google.com/p/coreemu/wiki/Namespaces.

To create a namespace named test and run a command under this namespace just run

```
ip netns add test
ip netns exec test COMMAND
```

where COMMAND can be for example your shell or just the server script.

Answer (score 0):

It solves
https://github.com/hub4ops/vagrant/blob/main/Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|    
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"    
  config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265"    
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL    
    ip route del 0/0
    ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.1.1
    echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
  SHELL
end
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/441285)